# How to echo the image from the Mysql database using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am learning MYSQL and PHP. I want to upload the image and show the image by retrieving it from the database. Everything is good but I am not able to show the image. Please help me below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Image Uploader</title></head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","logon");
    if(!$con){
        echo "not connected";
    }else{
        echo "connectedsuccessfully";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $image=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $sql="insert into image(name,image) values('$name','$image') ";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $sqli="select image from image";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: `$image=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` contains the filename, not the image!

Answer (score 0):

Akash kumar, you can use the code below to get the image or any file name without extension.

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

*And Echo it. !*

Answer (score 0):

your output clearly show that the location of the image is incorrect. and you dont need to use base64_encode.
just

```
echo '<img src="your_path_iamge/"'.$row[image]
[....]
```